# Importing functional Component in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a hook based functional component and trying to import that functional component in the class-based component, but I'm getting this below error

[image]

functional component code :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [searchBtn, setSearchBtn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
      <input className="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
      {searchBtn ? (
        <button
          title="Back"
          onClick={() => setSearchBtn(false)}
          className="search-btn "
        />
      ) : (
        <button
          title="Search"
          onClick={() => setSearchBtn(true)}
          className="search-btn "
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I am using the react-dom version: 16.8.6

Comment: Can you show how you are importing this functional component inside a class component?

Answer (score 0):

**Rules of Hooks**

Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

for better understanding check this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: i have written hooks appropriately, I am getting an error while importing the hooks component in class component

Comment: @bajran you are using hooks component inside class component which isn't recommended. better to use functional component and handle functions from parent component to child(functional) component.

Comment: can you please let me know why it is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your component. The most common case for your error is using some third party component that expects a function to render something (and calls it as a function) rather than a react component:

```
// how you expect it to be called
<SearchBar />
...
// how it is actually called
{SearchBar()}
```

if that's the case, change it from `someProp={SearchBar}` to `someProp={() => <SearchBar />}`